# Organizing the Disk and Folder Structure for an Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, partitioning

I'm using Ubuntu as a LAMP server.  I'd like to arrange the disk partition and folder structure for an easy upgrade to the next Ubuntu version.

In Windows it can be: `A: windows` `B: program files` `C: data`.
How should this be done in Ubuntu? 
Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned LAMPP. Did you mean the lampp stack from the repositories or http://www.xampp.org/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu can easily be upgraded without losing data. Because Ubuntu knows where each application resides (thanks to `apt`), there is no need for a separate directory for applications.

You'll mostly be fine with a separate `/home` directory, in case you want to wipe your root partition or clone your home directory. All user settings and documents are stored in `/home`.

Comment: please can you explain with example why its better to have also /home partition + security issue

Comment: A recent example: my friend was cloning his disk to his home folder, but ran out of space. Because the root partition and home folder resided on the same partition, no log files could be written either (1 reason). Having a partition instead of a folder allows you to set disk quotas for a specific partition, this is usually not interesting for home users, but is included for completeness.